# Simple Regex Doesn't match

Tags: c#, c++, regex, unit-testing, com

I have a simple C++, COM-visible, regex utility that returns true/false depending on whether it finds a match. Expressions like `A` `[A]` (borrowing from the method signature in a unit test) match. A nice expression to match Excel range strings `(A1:Z10)` works just fine. But an expression like

```
This is a long sentence.
```

`[A-Za-Z]*` with or without ignore capitalization, won't match. I've tried the variations I can think of: `\w[A-Z]*` (ignore caps set), a .NET variety \p... (something, can't remember now!). Nothing works. Interestingly, I have two different regex tester plug-ins in VS2012, and they both say the regex does match on the sentence.

/EDIT/
Don't think this will help much, but here's the operative part of the C++ code:

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
varRegex.ChangeType(VT_BSTR);

    using namespace std::regex_constants;
    wregex regexPredicate((wchar_t*)varRegex.bstrVal, ECMAScript|icase);

    if (varValue.vt == VT_BSTR)
    {
        pRetVal->vt = VT_BOOL;
        pRetVal->boolVal = std::regex_match( static_cast<wchar_t*>(varValue.bstrVal), regexPredicate ) 
            ? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE;
    }
```

Hmm... I must be using incorrectly.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: [A-Za-z] this regex match all letter upper and lower case

Comment: Can you put some code in your question, especially about how you're applying the regex?

Answer (score 2):

For your example string `This is a long sentence.` you need to use a quantifier.

```
[a-zA-Z\. ]*   matches any character of a-z or A-Z, ' ' and '.' (0 or more times)
```

The following quantifiers are recognized.

```
*      Match 0 or more times
+      Match 1 or more times
?      Match 1 or 0 times
{n}    Match exactly n times
{n,}   Match at least n times
{n,m}  Match at least n but not more than m times
```

Comment: Really thought changing the quantifier from star to plus would do it, but no joy.

Comment: Maybe include the punctuation. `[a-zA-Z\. ]+`

Answer (score 0):

> "This is a long sentence." "[A-Za-Z]"

You probably meant "[A-Za-z]" //last "z" is small

Comment: Yep. Typo strikes again!